# Dealing with noise in arduino interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, software

I'm makeing two modules,
module2 gets sensor signal, and send wireless message to module1, with HC-12. Then module1 is going to do some work it is supposed to do. Circuit configuration is in the picture.

I tested HC-12 communication, and they send, receive well. But my problem is that,
when module1 gets turned ON, Interrupt gets activated (LOW) and module2 sends signal that's not supposed to send. It seems it is because of electromagnetic wave noise, from HC-12.

How can I filter this noise, using code ? Now I'm stuck for the last 3 days.

[image]

`code`
Module1

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// #define IDlen 4
#define maxID 5

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
int upButtonPin = 7;
int selectButtonPin = 6;
int downButtonPin = 5;
int sensors[maxID] = {1001,9999,9999,9999,9999};
int receivedID = 0;
int currentPos = 0;
String rcvMsg = "xxxx";

//void printSensor(int intID);
void menu();
void showAllSensors();
int removeID(int senNumInt);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial began.");

  mySerial.begin(9600);
//  mySerial.println("0000");
  
  lcd.begin();
  pinMode(upButtonPin,  INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(selectButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(downButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
  rcvMsg = "xxxx";
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Ready");
  if(digitalRead(upButtonPin)==LOW){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Up btn pressed!");
  }
  if(digitalRead(downButtonPin)==LOW){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Down btn pressed!");
  }
  if(digitalRead(selectButtonPin)==LOW){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Registered sensors:");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    showAllSensors();
    menu();
  }
  if(mySerial.available()>0){
    
//    String rcvMsg = mySerial.readStringUntil('\n');
    rcvMsg = mySerial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.print("Received msg: ");
    Serial.print(rcvMsg);
    Serial.print('\n');
    receivedID = rcvMsg.substring(0,4).toInt();
    Serial.println(receivedID);
    delay(50);
    
    for (int i=0;i<maxID;i++){
      if(sensors[i] == receivedID){
        String temp = String(receivedID);
        String ack = String(temp + "01"); // 01: success 02: reject (ID does not exist)
        mySerial.println(ack);
        Serial.print("Ack sent: ");
        Serial.print(ack);
      }
    }
  }
}

void menu(){
  lcd.print("UP: add sensor");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("DOWN: del sensor");
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  
  while(1){  
    if(digitalRead(upButtonPin)==LOW){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Add sensor:");
      delay(1500);
      lcd.clear();
      int senNumInt = 1000;
      char senNum[IDlen];
      sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);
      
      while(1){   
        lcd.print(senNum);
        if(digitalRead(upButtonPin)==LOW){
          senNumInt++;
          sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
        }
        if(digitalRead(downButtonPin)==LOW){
          senNumInt--;
          sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
        }
        if(digitalRead(selectButtonPin)==LOW){
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
          lcd.setCursor(0,1);
          lcd.print("Menu: OK, Down: Cancel");
          //센서 입력값을 받아서, 리스트에 넣어 놓기
          sensors[currentPos] = senNumInt;
          lcd.clear();
          showAllSensors();       
          delay(1500);
          break; // 값 입력 후 저장한 것 보여주고... 나가기.
        }
        delay(200);
        lcd.clear();
      }
      delay(200);
      break;
    } // up button 누름 메뉴 끝

    if(digitalRead(downButtonPin)==LOW){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Remove sensor:");
      delay(1500);
      lcd.clear();
      int senNumInt = 1000;
      char senNum[IDlen];
      sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);

      while(1){   
        lcd.print(senNum);
        if(digitalRead(upButtonPin)==LOW){
          senNumInt++;
          sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
        }
        if(digitalRead(downButtonPin)==LOW){
          senNumInt--;
          sprintf(senNum, "%d", senNumInt);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
        }
        if(digitalRead(selectButtonPin)==LOW){
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print(senNum);
          lcd.setCursor(0,1);
          lcd.print("Delete sensor");
          delay(600);
          lcd.clear();
          
          //센서 입력값을 받아서, 리스트에서 찾은 후 삭제
          int result = removeID(senNumInt);
          if(result==1){
            lcd.print("Deleted.");
            showAllSensors();       
          }else{
            lcd.print("No such ID!!");
          };
          delay(1500);
          break; // 값 입력 후 저장한 것 보여주고... 나가기.
        }
        delay(200);
        lcd.clear();
      }
      delay(200);
      break;
    } // down button 누름 메뉴 끝
    
    
    
    delay(200);
  }
  return;
}

void showAllSensors(){
  char imsi[IDlen];
  for(int i=0;i<maxID;i++){
    Serial.println(sensors[i]);
    sprintf(imsi, "%d", sensors[i]);
    lcd.print(imsi);
    delay(800);
    lcd.clear();
  }
  return;
}

int removeID(int senNumInt){
  int isFound = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<maxID;i++){
    if(sensors[i] == senNumInt){
      sensors[i] = 9999;
      isFound = 1;
    }
  }
  return isFound;
}
```

`code`Module2

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h> 
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

SimpleTimer timer;
const int wakeUpPin = 2; // pin of interrupt 0
const int LED = 8;
const int numMsg = 1; // For the safety, send multiple messages, everytime.  
boolean armed = false;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(4,5);
String ID = "1001";
String code = "01";
String msg = "xxxx";
String rcvMsg = "xxxx";
int timerID = 0;
boolean isWaked = false;
int pulseWidth = 0;

/*
  Communication protocol
  01: powered on
  02: Sensor touched (Feed is full)
  03: alive
*/

void setup()
{
  String msg = String(ID + code);
  pinMode(wakeUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  timerID = timer.setInterval(1000, sendMsg);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  mySerial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println(msg);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() // 반복
{
  pulseWidth = pulseIn(wakeUpPin, LOW, 100000);
  Serial.println("start loop.");
  armed = true;
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Now sleeping.."); 
  delay(200);
  sleepNow(); 

  Serial.println(pulseWidth);
  if(armed){
    Serial.println("Waked up. Send Feed full msg.");
    
    delay(200);
    code = "02";
    msg = String(ID + code);
    sendMsg();
    int count = 0;
    while(1){
      count++;
      if(count>200){      //prevent infinite loop
        count = 0;
        break;
      }
      Serial.print('*');
      if(mySerial.available()>0){
        Serial.println("RECEIVED!!!!");
        rcvMsg = mySerial.readStringUntil('\n');
        if(rcvMsg.substring(0,4).equals(ID)){
//          timer.deleteTimer(timerID);
          Serial.println("My msg is received successfully. Now sleep again..\n");
          break;
        }
      }
      delay(50);  
    }
    armed = false;
  }
}  

void wakeUpNow(){
  isWaked = true;
  return;
}

void sleepNow(){
  Serial.println("Entered sleep now()");
  delay(100);
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); 
  sleep_enable(); 
  attachInterrupt(0,wakeUpNow, LOW); 
  sleep_mode(); 
  // When wakes up, resume codes from here. 
  sleep_disable(); 
  
  
  detachInterrupt(0);   
  return;
}

void sendMsg(){
  for (int i=0;i<numMsg;i++){
    mySerial.println(msg);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a diagnostic test or an answer, because they may be roughly the same thing.  I'm guessing your testing these in close proximity.  What I'd tell you to do is put a stronger pull-up on pin 2.  Put 1kOhm (just to pick a number) from pin 2 to 5V and switch `pinMode` to `INPUT` rather than `INPUT_PULLUP`.  See what, if any, difference that makes.

Comment: emi/rfi choke collars/ferrite "beads" on vcc and signal wires might solve your problem in hardware. Try some from an old miniUSB cord and see if they help.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is not exactly what you asked for, but I recommend hardware filtering. I had problems with noise on interrupts and I was able to solve that with this component: https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/emi-filtering-and-signal-conditioning/integrated-emi-filtering-and-esd-protection/computer-legacy-port-ipad/kbmf.html#overview

It is not expensive and saves you a lot of headache.
If you can't use SMD components, you can rebuild the circuit of that filter with capacitors and resistors, just be sure, that you put the filter as close as possible to the interrupt pin.